# Characteristic of a ring where for each r in R we have $r^3+2r^2+r=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

What is the Characteristic of a unital ring $R$, where for each $r \in R$ we have $r^3+2r^2+r=0$?

Comment: Is the ring assumed to be commutative and unital?

Comment: The ring is just unital but not commutative@Arthur

Comment: Then set $r=1$?

Comment: For $r^3+2r^2+r=0$

Comment: For that $\,0 = f(-2) = -2.\ $ The characteristic must divide $\,\gcd(f(0),f(\pm1),f(\pm2),\ldots)\ \ $

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}_2$ for example  the both of r=1 and r=-2 are true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the non-unital case: Set $f(x)=x^3+2x^2+x$ and note that (in general rings)

$$ f(r) + f(-r) = 4r^2 $$

and therefore

$$ f(2r) = 8r^3+8r^2+2r = 2r\bigl(f(r)+f(-r)\bigr) + 2\bigl(f(r)+f(-r)\bigr) + 2r $$

Thus, if we assume that $f$ always evaluates to $0$ in the ring we're looking at, then this simplifies to $2r=0$ for arbitrary $r$.

Comment: Thank you so much  that was great

Answer (score 1):

@Bill Dubuque's comment shows that the characteristic of $R$ is $2$.  The relation then becomes $r^3=r$ for all $r\in R$, and a ring satisfying this relation must be commutative.  All of this is true even if you don't assume $R$ has an identity: put $r=-2s$ in the original identity to get $2s=0$ for any $s\in R$.

Edit: See @Troposphere's answer for more detail in the non-unital case.  You first need to show $4r^2=0$ for all $r$.

Comment: The pedant in me notes that the characteristic could be $1$; that is, $R$ could be the trivial ring (unless this is ruled out by fiat as is sometimes done).  Identities can only give you a maximum possible characteristic.

Comment: @Toby Bartels: good point.

Comment: How does putting $r = -2s$ give $2s = 0$? Does $-8s^3 + 8s^2 - 2s = 0$ imply $2s = 0$?

Comment: Although it's not really necessary for the OP, I'm not getting the non-unital case.  If I set $r:=-2s$, then I get $2s(4s^2-4s+1)=0$, not $2s=0$.  (ETA: Same comment as Rob's, although I believe that Rob's expression has a sign error.)

Comment: @TobyBartels: thanks for pointing out the sign error - now fixed.

Comment: @RobArthan, not quite what the answer seems to say, but: We have $f(s)+f(-s)=4s^2$, so $4s^2=0$ for every $s$. But then the first two terms in $f(2s)$ vanish and we're left with $2s=0$.

Comment: @Troposphere: thanks! I think it would be useful to include that in your answer.

Comment: @Troposphere :  Agreed, that fixes it.  (I'm always coming in right behind Rob.  But it's Allen's answer, not Troposphere's.)

Comment: Thank you  very much 